# Custom table cell background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, three20

I'm taking my first stab at the three20 iPhone framework and I can't seem to figure out how to change the background of a table cell to a UIImage instead of just the color.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the `backgroundColor` of the cell's `contentView` with an image pattern like this:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

This will work if the cell is a `UITableViewCell` or a three20 `TTTableViewCell` derivative (since they derive from `UITableViewCell`)

Comment: But this produces Memory issues when using this PatternImage maximum in application. And also Crashes the application some times.

Comment: @Jasmine I'm not totally sure what you mean by PatternImage maximum. The method recommended above is a standard iOS call, if there is crashing or memory issues it is likely other code. However, an investigation using Instruments should shed some light. If it truly is a bug then please submit to Apple. If you have a new question concerning my answer or the method, please submit it as a new question. Thanks!